# Find All WebI Reports that Use Free-hand SQL

Tags: business-objects

We are on 4.1 SP06 Patch 4.

Is there a way to find all Web Intelligence reports in which free-hand SQL is being used?

Thanks

Comment: I got the Tumbleweed badge for this. So proud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the **SI_FHSQL_RELATIONAL_CONNECTION** property in QueryBuilder indicates the presence of free-hand SQL provided its **SI_TOTAL** child property is greater than 0. I am only concerned with Web Intelligence reports so I can filter on that too...

```
select * 
from CI_INFOOBJECTS 
where SI_KIND = 'Webi' 
and SI_FHSQL_RELATIONAL_CONNECTION.SI_TOTAL > 0
```

One exception seems to be that if a report had free-hand SQL at some point, but then that query gets deleted this property doesn't get reset.